# iCloud Photo Library not uploading anymore

Tags: ios, icloud, photo-stream

I have iCloud photo library enabled on my iPhone (6, iOS 8.3).
Since the weekend it does not upload the photos anymore.
When I go to the Photos settings, it gives me the following messages in a loop:

> 2324 Objects waiting for upload
>   Uploading 2324 objects

The progressbar shows up, fills up to around 30%, then disapears again.
I translated the messages from German, they might be different when iOS is set to English.
A restart of the phone does not help.

When I go to iCloud.com the photos are not there and also in Photos on my Mac I cannot see them. However when I create a shared album, I get the photos on Photos on my Mac.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I tried Photo Library briefly and had a similar problem. The progress bar would go to about 40% then disappear. The problem for me was a lack of storage space, and so it would just fail at a certain point. Go to General > iCloud > Storage to check the amount of space available on your iCloud account, then check the amount your photos take up (I believe this can only be done in iTunes). If the photos don't fit in the available space either buy more space or just turn off the feature as it wastes battery if it is not actually being useful.

Comment: Thanks, though I have 200GB of Space of which 80Gb are still available.